# Help with Collocations #1

Tags: collocations

I really need your help with this. I get extremely frustrated when I don’t know how to know the right use of these cases. Please extend your help by providing me any websites or tips to fully understand and explore this. Consider these sentences.

1- **The sentence wording is wrong here**.

A. Can you say “ **the wording sentence**” or “ **the word sentences**”?

B. If you do change the order of these two words, how would the meaning be different?
How are you able to know which one goes first?

2- **Let me take this car for a test drive.**

A. Can you say “ **a testing drive**” Or “ **a drive test**” Why not?

B. Please highlight the difference.

3 - **Where are the indicator lights**?

A. Can you say “the light indicators” ?

B. Again, what is the difference and how can you know which one goes first?

C. What is the correct format or the grammar to these collocations? 
MOST IMPORTANTLY, How can I know the difference and be able to form these collocations correctly??

Please help me as much as you can with sources/websites/ tips/ anything that might help me know how to know the difference and use the right form.

Comment: You have several very different questions that are about a similar topic, you might be better served to ask them a bit more separately.

Comment: You are right !! I just felt to put all the questions in my head in one question. !!

Comment: Ask about sentences 5 to 7 in another question(i have some questions about them too). for sentence number 3 you can check this [link](http://www.learnenglish.de/mistakes/drivetest.html).

Comment: You should ask 3 different questions. one for sentence 1, one for sentences 2 to 4 and one for sentences 5 to 7.

Comment: You are asking about compound nouns. you can check this [link](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/compound-nouns). read the link carefully, hope you get why you can't say _light indicators_.

Comment: or if you say _light indicators_ the meaning would be different.

Answer (score 1):

Indicator lights versus light indicators...

Indicator lights are lights that indicate.

Light indicators are either

a) indicators of something pertaining to light (its intensity or wavelength or saturation level or some such quality of light) or
b) indicators that do not use sound, or gauges, or vibration, but light to indicate whatever it is that they indicate.